# Selecting last cell in Column - Error 424?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am attempting to select the last cell in a column, copy it's value, and paste it into another workbook. In the first workbook, I've created a button in a space. Once you click that button, I want it to disappear, take the value from the other workbook (NCR Log), add 1 to the value, and paste it into the first workbook where the button used to be. I assumed this was going to be easy, but when I run the macro I get a Run-time error 424: Object Required. Does anything in here look strange? The log is just a set of columns and rows in excel... Nothing unique about it.

For Reference: NCR Log is the workbook I'm trying to get the value from. NCRDONE is the workbook I'm trying to put the value into. Column B in the log is where I want the last cell from. I4 is the cell in which I'd like the value to go in NCRDONE.

```
Sub tryingtoaDD()

With ActiveSheet
For Each Sh In .Shapes
    If Not Application.Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range("H3:J5")) Is Nothing Then
        Sh.Delete
    End If
Next Sh
End With

ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open ("R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR Log\NCR Log.xlsm")

ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select.Copy

Workbooks.Open ("R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR Log\NCRDONE.xlsm")

Range("I4").Select.Paste.Select


ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1




ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `.Select` it is a command like `.copy` or `.paste` and has no children.

Comment: `Range("I4").Paste` will paste it in for you. You dont need to select the cell as the code knows that I4 is where the paste needs to go

Comment: @Mr.Burns no, it won't. Range / cell object doesnt have a Paste method.

Comment: @DavidZemens you are right, I dont use copy/paste often in code, after checking it out you need to use `PasteSpecial` it seems

Comment: @Mr.Burns or Select and then ActiveSheet.Paste.  I make the same mistake as you though, always think i can do Range.Paste

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Sub tryingtoaDD()

Dim WBLog as Workbook
Dim WBDone as Workbook

With ActiveSheet
For Each Sh In .Shapes
    If Not Application.Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range("H3:J5")) Is Nothing Then
        Sh.Delete
    End If
Next Sh
End With

ScreenUpdating = False

Set WBLog = Workbooks.Open("R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR Log\NCR Log.xlsm")
Set WBDone = Workbooks.Open("R:\Quality\NCR's\NCR Log\NCRDONE.xlsm")
WBLog.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy _
    Destination:=WBDone.ActiveSheet.Range("I4")

ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1

ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In your original code, this will fail:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select.Copy
```

Because `Select` is a method that doesn't *return* an object, hence the 424 (Object Required) error: You're trying to call a method (`.Copy`) from a non-object.

This line will also fail for similar reasons.

```
Range("I4").Select.Paste.Select
```

Note that the `Copy` method has an optional parameter, `Destination` which we can use to specify exactly *where* the paste should result.  That's what I've done in the answer above.

Comment: You beat me to it and did a better job, you deserve my +1